# How to push Stack content to an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, push, element

I have a method that I want to write which has an integer stack as a parameter and I want to push all content from this stack into an integer array that I create within the method. How do I do this?

```
public void test(StackADT<Integer> stack)

{

SimpleListADT<Integer> values = new ArraySimpleList<Integer>();
// I want to push the content of the stack in the parameter to the list
// using a loop; the stacks will contain integers but they will be represented 
// as strings, not sure if I have the for loop set up correctly

for (int i = 0; i < stack.size();i++)
{
  String s = stack.get(i);
  values.addToRear(s); 
  // not sure what to put in the body of the loop here, I know the above is
  // incorrect because there's no get(int) method for stacks, I just need a
  // push in the right direction
}

}
```

Comment: look up how to iterate through collections. SO isn't a place to ask for coding to be done for you.

Comment: What array? Also, how is your StackADT implemented? `pop()`?

Comment: `StackADT` is not a Java-defined package, therefore we don't know anything about it and cannot help you use it.

Comment: You need to tell us about the APIs of these classes, since they aren't standard Java collections classes. Does `SimpleListADT` implement `java.util.List`? What about `StackADT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stack`s use `push` and `pop` methods. `Push` adds an element to the stack, whereas `pop` removes an element. You might also have access to `peek` to get the first (topmost) element of the stack without removing it.

You might want to do something like

```
while (!stack.isEmpty) {
 otherCollection.add(stack.pop());
}
```